# Extract / unzip a zip file in Angular7

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, unzip

I am using angular 7. I have a component that handles all the uploaded files and displays progress on UI.

Due to client-need, I have to add the functionality of uploading zip files for frontend in angular as there is no processing capability for .zip files at the server-side.

I googled for angular7 compatible unzip,
but options are not angular specific (standard). I don't want to include any js file in index.html.

Is there any library which provides this capability so when I upload a .zip file and it can extract its content. it should be Angular7 compatible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to unzip before the upload, then upload the individual files to the server? cause the server can't unzip?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to unzip before the upload, then upload the individual files to the server because I can't access the server or api.

Comment: You might want to look into [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/). Look at their demo on the site, maybe it will help you.